# Django CMS: 2 pages with same slug, but different publication dates

Tags: django, django-cms

Like the title says:
I would like to have 2 different CMS pages with same slug, but a different publication date.

E.g.

```
Page 1 -> slug: sale -> pub date *till*: 12-12-2013 11:00:00
Page 2 -> slug: sale -> pub date *from*: 12-12-2013 11:00:01
```

Is this possible with `django-cms`, or any other package?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with django-cms, but if `slug` is a unique field on the Page model (which is likely) there's probably a lot of code depending on this feature, so patching is gonna be messy as hell.

You could take some ideas from [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion)